# Configure Jenkins jobs depending on other jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

Currently I have one big job for a big C++ project, which does everything, compiling, running unit tests, coverage, release binaries and creating docs.

As the job takes 40 minutes I would like to split the job in different smaller ones.

I want to use the following approach:

- main job every 15 minutes, which checks out the SCM, compiles the Debug configuration and runs basic unit tests
- Several jobs for code analysis, coverage, integration tests, compiling Release builds and deployment to our application server running once per night, if the main job and each previous job were successful

I need the SVN revision, the build number and the workspace of the main job in all following jobs.

So far I was unable to achieve this.
The Parameterize Trigger plugin doesn't support triggers only once a day, the Build Trigger plugin doesn't support parameters, the built-in trigger also didn't work.
I understand that pipelines would probably make my approach easier, but e.g. my used CMake plugin won't support pipelines in a while.

Any other ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just configure a job with parameters (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) as post build job, for all your downstream jobs and this plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin.

As parameter you can pass any var you need like buildNr and workspace.

Or just have a look at Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to run the subsequent jobs only once at night, if  the main job during the day was a success on it's last run (depending on the last commit). As I said pipeline is currently not an option, because some of my needed plugins don't support it.

Comment: why not configure 2 jobs one nightly and one regular. Maybe promoted jobs plugin  is also an option